# Unsure how to generate Linq for my query SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following tables:
Tables definition:

**Season** (ID, Description, StartDate) 
**Game** (ID, SeasonID, Description, Date, Type, Publish, PlayerCount) 
**Result** (ID, PlayerID, GameID, Position, Points)  
**Player** (ID, Surname, Forename, etc...)

I would like to know which seasons a player has taken part in. Could someone point me in the right direction for getting my linq query using EF for this please? I'm running into a road block. I pretty sure I need to use a Distinct() somewhere but just can't figure it out.

Comment: can you post you tables definition ?

Comment: Yeah sure... Season (ID, Description, StartDate) - Game (ID, SeasonID, Description, Date, Type, Publish, PlayerCount) - Result (ID, PlayerID, GameID, Position, Points) - Player (ID, Surname, Forename, etc...). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of `Season` objects and call `Distinct`:

```
int playerID = {something};

var seasons = (from s in db.Seasons
               join g in db.Games on s.ID equals g.SeasonID
               join r in db.Results on g.ID equals r.GameID
               where r.PlayerID == playerID
               select s
              ).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's just the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to join your tables together (making some assumptions about the table definitions):

```
from s in seasons
join g in games on s.Id equals g.seasonId
join r in results on g.Id equals r.gameId
join p in players on r.Id equals p.resultId
where p.Id == playerIdYouCareAbout
select s.whatever
```

That will get you the seasons, from there you can use `Distinct` if needed.